# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'unregisteredUserPost' resolved to null

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, cdi

I'm trying to implement a simple guestbook.

[image]

When user clicks "Submit", the `UnregisteredUserPost` CDI bean is supposed to be instantiated. However, instead I get the following exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: /guestbook.xhtml @11,57 value="#{unregisteredUserPost.name}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'unregisteredUserPost' resolved to null
```

I will appreaciate if you help me to find the root cause of the problem.

**guestbook.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
  <h:head>
    <title>#{msg.page_title}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css"/>
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputText value="#{msg.your_name}&#160;"/>
        <h:inputText value="#{unregisteredUserPost.name}"/>
        <br/><br/>
        <h:outputText value="#{msg.your_msg}"/>
        <br/>
        <h:inputTextarea 
            rows="5" cols="100" value="#{unregisteredUserPost.content}"/>
        <br/><br/>
        <h:commandButton 
            value="#{msg.submit}" action="#{unregisteredUserPost}"/>
    </h:form>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

**UnregisteredUserPost.java**

```
package learning.javaee.guestbook;

import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class UnregisteredUserPost extends AbstractPost {
    private String name;
    private OffsetDateTime dateTime;

    public UnregisteredUserPost() {}

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public OffsetDateTime getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }
    public void setDateTime(OffsetDateTime dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }
}
```

**AbstractPost.java**

```
package learning.javaee.guestbook;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.interceptor.AroundConstruct;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;

@Named
public abstract class AbstractPost implements Serializable {
    private String content;

    @Inject
    private static Logger log;

    @AroundConstruct
    private void logConstruction(InvocationContext ic) {
        try {
            ic.proceed();
            log.fine("Created " + getClass().getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.severe(e.toString());
        }
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

**beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" 
            id="WebApp_ID" 
            version="3.1">
    <display-name>guestbook1</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>guestbook.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config   xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
                    version="2.2">
    <application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
        </locale-config>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>MessagesBundle</base-name>
            <var>msg</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

Comment: Looks not so bad. Two things I see. 1. Why is your bean SessionScoped? Do you want to handle the instance state your self? Make it event or view scoped is enough for the form. Because you want new instance for an empty form. 2. What should happen with the action="unregisteredUserPost" on the button? You need to pass a method to the action attribute, could be a bean that can save a post ;) The rest is ok, you have a beans.xml to activate CDI, you define webprofile 3.1 and jsf 2.2 which is all fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're missing `bean-discovery-mode="all"` in your *beans.xml* . CDI needs this directive to inject the bean, from your explicit archive.

**Related**

- [CDI deployment configuration](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/cdi-adv001.htm)